# How do I compile and install an addition kernel on a Debian System

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, debian

I have to install an old kernel Version for my Debian distribution, to check if a driver has version problem. The driver is supported and tested only with a kernel version up to 2.6. My Debian has an 3.2 kernel. Because the hardware works not correctly I contacted the support and the told me to try an older kernel version, but I don't want to reinstall my whole system because of this test. I know it is possible to select different kernel versions at the boot menu, but how can I add a kernel there?

Getting an older kernel version and compiling it is not the problem but how do I add the new "old" kernel to the boot menu and where do I have to store this kernel without killing my actual kernel

Answer (score 0):

Kernels images must be in your `/boot` directory and also grub bootloader configuration file there at `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`

If you will open `grub.cfg` you can see settings of grub menu (it is startup menu when you're turning on your computer). It must looks like this (my grub.cfg):

```
menuentry 'Ubuntu' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os
$menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-79b185ec-dcb5-4f70-9ea9-6cee082cc626' {
    recordfail
    load_video
    gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,msdos1'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1  79b185ec-dcb5-4f70-9ea9-6cee082cc626
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 79b185ec-dcb5-4f70-9ea9-6cee082cc626
    fi
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.18.0-rc4+ root=UUID=79b185ec-dcb5-4f70-9ea9-6cee082cc626 ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.18.0-rc4+
}
submenu 'Advanced options for Ubuntu' $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-advanced-79b185ec-dcb5-4f70-9ea9-6cee082cc626' {
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.18.0-rc4+' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.18.0-rc4+-advanced-79b185ec-dcb5-4f70-9ea9-6cee082cc626' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos1'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1  79b185ec-dcb5-4f70-9ea9-6cee082cc626
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 79b185ec-dcb5-4f70-9ea9-6cee082cc626
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.18.0-rc4+ ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.18.0-rc4+ root=UUID=79b185ec-dcb5-4f70-9ea9-6cee082cc626 ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.18.0-rc4+
    }
    # other submenes
    ....
    ....
    ....
    #
}
```

You can see menu entries and submenus here, so you can add yet another menu/submenu item with your settings for kernel path, initrd path and etc...